# How can I make `query` and `mutation` work on websocket connection in graphql?

Tags: node.js, websocket, graphql, apollo, graphql-js

I'd like to use graphql on top of websocket connection. After some searching, graphql supports `subscription` which can be built on top of websocket. Server can publish data to client once they subscribed.
I have found a library https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws which can support websocket connection.

However, the `query` and `mutation` are still on http connection. Do I understand it correctly? If yes, how can I make `query` and `mutation` uses websocket connection as well?